# What is the use of Android System WebView?

Tags: system, webview

I have seen some Android phones where this application comes installed on the device. What is the use of this application?

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG: Tem]

Does installing this app have any advantage on any other Android devices which does not have this application installed?

Comment: It's been available since Kitkat and the apps which takes advantage of it can open the webpages in themselves (their activities) unlike those which always asks you to open them separately in a browser. E.g. Facebook on Android 4.4 and above loads the external links into itself rather than asking you to open them in a browser. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html and https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview

Comment: The above should be the answer and not a comment.

Comment: @Firelord So if I open Fb application and when I click a news article from the application with the help of the Android web view it will open the News article on top of the application and under the task manager it will show only Fb and not the browser through which the news is loaded.

Comment: Why cannot we embed default webView in separate fragment or activity and pass url to load in our app itself ?  I have done similar in this GitHub POC - https://github.com/hiteshsahu/Android-Universal-Web-Content-Loader .

Answer (score 8):

Some applications require what is known as WebView, a mini browser for functions like approving logins from Facebook and Google+. This is essentially a miniature version of Chrome.

It used to be that WebView only updated with the OS. In Lollipop, Google detached it from the Core OS in a way, and added the functionality for it to be updated via Google Play, like other apps, automatically. This allows it to keep up with Chrome and provide a better browsing experience.

The next time you log into an app and you are brought to a Web Page in the app saying "Allow 'The App' to assess your Google Account" or what not, see if you get get to the Google homepage via the "About Google" link. Then search for and open http://WhatBrowser.Org You will see how it is a mini chrome-based browser inside the app, provided by the system, and updated by Google Play.

Having this installed will keep it updated. You will not have to wait to upgrade the Android OS.

Comment: Probably one of the best reason why WebView update is now independent of Android OS is because of [WebView vulnerability on Android 4.3 and before](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-avoid-the-android-jellybean-webview-vulnerability/). With the update being independent, the vulnerability can be fixed without the need to wait for OS update (though it's only for Android 5.0 and later).

Comment: I don't use Chrome Browser,Google+ and Facebook. I have disabled these apps. Should I disable Android System Webview app too?

Comment: means do I need Android System Webview app?

Comment: "I don't use Chrome Browser,Google+ and Facebook. I have disabled these apps. Should I disable Android System Webview app too?" --- Some applications, other than those you mentioned, use WebView. I suggest you leave it on. There used to be a vulnerability in the previous version of WebView but this has been fixed from 4.4 onwards (at this point WebView changed and [is based on Chromium](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview)). From 5.5 onwards, WebView became an independent component from the OS and thus appears as an application.

Comment: How is an Android N based device despite having it disabled is able to open webpages within the respective app

Comment: @user285oo6 From Android N, there is no more need for the System Webview. Chrome is used directly by embedding apps instead.