# I deactivated Android System Webview. What can go wrong?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

I'm a day 1 Firefox user. I recently faced lots of changes in Google's apps like News or Google (Now) that forced me to use Chrome from within the app, against my will.

I read that I could deactivate Chrome to have taps on Google's apps open links in my Firefox as they used to. So I did and it worked. But sometimes there's that video that Firefox can't read but Chrome can so the solution was only half good.

Today I learned about Android System WebView. It's the component that allows Chrome to run in other apps, amongst other things I think. I decided to deactivate this one instead and everything seems as I want again.

But what are the consequences of this action in the long term? Are there side effects I should fear?

Comment: Well nevermind, some apps still use Chrome and not ASWV. I finally had to deactivate Chrome as well. The question is still valid in itself so I don't delete it.

Comment: Related, or dupe: [What is the use of Android System WebView?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/119251/what-is-the-use-of-android-system-webview). In short: it's better to have it enabled, unless you're sure about the possible security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1):

The Webview is used to open websites in apps so that you are not redirected to the internet browser every time an app tries to open a url (this includes sign-in urls) and apps that run off a website might not operate properly if the Webview is disabled.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).